# How to load images asynchronously with webpack

Tags: javascript, dynamic, reactjs, background-image, webpack

I am attempting to load an image dynamically based on props in a react component.

So far this is what I have come up with:

**MyComponent.jsx** *(uses [ES7 property initializers syntax](http://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2015/01/27/react-v0.13.0-beta-1.html#es7-property-initializers))*

```
//...

const getIcon = (iconName) => {
  require.ensure([], require => {
    cb = () => require(`../../images/icons/${iconName}`)
  })
}

class MyComponent extends Component {
  state = {
    categoryIcon: getIcon.bind(this, this.props.icon)
  };

  render() {
    let iconStyle = {backgroundImage: `url('${this.state.categoryIcon}')`}

    return(
      <div className={styles.categoryIcon}
           style={iconStyle}
      ></div>
    )
  }
}
```

Executing it produces this error:

`GET http://localhost:3000/function%20()%20%7B%20[native%20code]%20%7D 404 (Not Found)`

---

**So, my question has multiple parts.**

1. Is loading images asynchronously possible using `require.ensure()` with webpack?

   - If so, how?
   - If not...
2. Can I load images asynchronously with webpack?

   - If so, how?
3. Based on my example is there anything else I should consider?

Comment: It seems that the callback function is being passed instead of being executed. I have tried adding a return statement 

`return cb()` 

and also wrapping the callback function in an iife

`cb = (() => require(`../../images/icons/${iconName}.svg`))()`

both produce the same error

Comment: I get undefined if I do this:

`
componentWillMount = (this.setState({categoryIcon: this.getIcon(this.props.icon)}))
  
  getIcon = (iconName) => {
    require.ensure([], require => {
      require(`../../images/icons/${iconName}.svg`)
    })
  };
`

Answer (score 2):

**I solved this with the following code:**

```
(iconName) => {
  require.ensure([], require => {
  require(`../../images/icons/${iconName}.svg`)
  })
}

class MyComponent extends Component {
  state = {
    categoryIcon: require(`../../images/icons/${this.props.icon}.svg`)
  };
```

Reading the webpack docs on [code splitting](https://webpack.github.io/docs/code-splitting.html) more carefully helped.

Comment: I have tested this solution with inline images using url-loader and it also works.

Comment: Won't the images end up in the bundle now?

Comment: If you inline them yes.  Otherwise individual files are created for each image.

Comment: Could you explain how this solved your problem? How does the block of code outside the component help?